# Checking if two strings contain the same characters, not considering their frequencies

Tags: python

I have two dictionary corresponding to character counts of two different strings. I want to check if they are made up of same characters or not, **regardless of the frequencies of the characters.**

---

Say, I have two strings `caars` and `racs`
They are made up of same characters `a,c,r,s`

---

I know of `cmp` method to compare two dictionaries, which also compares both the key-value pairs. But I don't want to compare their values or counts.

---

Just in case, you may ask, why do I have dict then for both the strings. Well, I do need them in some other part of the problem. So, why not use them.

---

How can I do this in python quickly?

Comment: Seems that you have a dictionary for each string; eg: `caars = {'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'r': 1, 's': 1}`, Is it true? And do you have the original string yet? If you have the original string so the `set` answer is the best method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

```
In [32]: str1 = 'caars'

In [33]: str2 = 'rats'

In [34]: set(str1) == set(str2)
Out[34]: False

In [35]: str3 = 'racs'

In [36]: set(str1) == set(str3)
Out[36]: True
```

Comment: Since you're using a `dict`, you can just compare directly by using `dict.viewkeys()` (python 2.x), or `dict.keys()` (python 3.x).

Comment: True, I had missed that little part.